# Motion in a time-dependent uniform magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics, induction

Suppose you have an infinite solenoid generating an **uniform magnetic field** inside.  The field is oriented along the solenoid axis : unit vector $\vec{\bf n}$.  The field intensity varies *linearly* with time between $t_1$ and $t_2 = t_1 + \Delta t$, like this (we neglect all electromagnetic *waves* here) :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
B(t) = B_1 + \lambda \, (B_2 - B_1)(t - t_1),
\end{equation}
where $B_1$ is the constant magnetic field for time $t < t_1$, $B_2$ is the constant magnetic field for time $t > t_2 = t_1 + \Delta t$, and $\lambda = 1/\Delta t$.  The time variation of this field generates an induced electric field inside the solenoid, for the same time interval (from $t_1$ to $t_2$) :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\vec{\bf E} = -\, \frac{1}{2} \; \lambda \; \Delta B \; \vec{\bf n} \times \vec{\bf r},
\end{equation}
where $\Delta B = B_2 - B_1 > 0$ is a simple constant (the magnetic field is increasing in the solenoid).  Take note that the unit vector $\vec{\bf n}$ is also a constant (the solenoid's axis).

Now, you drop a positive charge particle inside the solenoid : $q > 0$, with any position and initial velocity.  The equation of motion is this :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\frac{d \vec{\bf p}}{d t} = q \, \vec{\bf E} + q \, \vec{\bf v} \times \vec{\bf B},
\end{equation}
where $\vec{\bf p} = \gamma \, m \, \vec{\bf v}$ is the relativistic linear momentum of the particle.  I'm not interested in solving analytically this equation (I've done it numerically using ***Mathematica***.  The 3D curves are pretty !).  Now, the problem is this :

How can we find ***analytically*** the final energy at time $t > t_2$, as a function of the field intensities $B_1$, $B_2$ and the initial velocity (or energy) at time $t < t_1$ ?

I know that there is at least one *exact* constant of motion for this problem :
\begin{align}
\mathcal{J} &= \vec{\bf n} \cdot \big( \vec{\bf r} \times (\vec{\bf p} + q \, \vec{\bf A}) \big), \\[18pt]
&= \vec{\bf n} \cdot \big( \vec{\bf r} \times \gamma \, m \, \vec{\bf v} + \frac{q}{2} \; B(t) \, \vec{\bf r} \times (\vec{\bf n} \times \vec{\bf r})\big), \tag{4}
\end{align}
where $\vec{\bf A}$ is the potential-vector :
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\vec{\bf A} = \frac{1}{2} \; B(t) \, \vec{\bf n} \times \vec{\bf r}.
\end{equation}

We could also try to use the kinetic energy theorem (the magnetic field doesn't do any work) :
\begin{align}
\Delta K = W_{\text{em}} &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} q \, \vec{\bf E} \cdot \vec{\bf v} \; dt \\[18pt]
&\equiv -\, \frac{q}{2} \; \lambda \, \Delta B \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec{\bf n} \cdot (\vec{\bf r} \times \vec{\bf v}) \, dt, \tag{6}
\end{align}
but unfortunately it's not helping since I don't know how to evaluate this integral (take note that the vector $\vec{\bf r} \times \vec{\bf v}$ isn't conserved here, and it's not exactly the particle's angular momentum since the relativistic $\gamma$ factor is missing).  However, we recognize the time integral of the particle's *magnetic moment* $\vec{\boldsymbol{\mu}}(t)$ :
\begin{equation}\tag{7}
\vec{\boldsymbol{\mu}}(t) = \frac{q}{2} \; \vec{\bf r}(t) \times \vec{\bf v}(t),
\end{equation}
so we could write the following kinetic energy variation, but it doesn't help much :
\begin{equation}\tag{8}
\Delta K = -\, \langle \, \vec{\boldsymbol{\mu}} \, \rangle \cdot \Delta \vec{\bf B}.
\end{equation}
The constant of motion $\mathcal{J}$ isn't of any help in this case, even if the motion is constrained to the plane orthogonal to $\vec{\bf n}$ (i.e. motion in the solenoid's cross section).

Any suggestion to find the kinetic energy variation $\Delta K$ ?

I also suspect that there may be another ***exact conserved quantity*** for this problem (total energy ?  total magnetic flux on the particle's path ?).  What may be the other conserved quantity ?

---

Here's a typical trajectory in the solenoid's orthogonal plane :

[A picture in the plane http://s10.postimg.org/87h0m0849/motion.jpg[/img]](http://s10.postimg.org/87h0m0849/motion.jpg[/img])

The large circle is the initial motion at time $t < t_1$ (classical circular motion, of radius $r_1 = \gamma_1 \, m \, v_1/ q \, B_1$).  The small circle inside is the final motion at time $t > t_2$ (another classical circular motion around the final magnetic field lines, of radius $r_2 = \gamma_2 \, m \, v_2/ q \, B_2$).  The path between both circles is the effect of the *time varying* magnetic field ***and*** of the induced electric field (which accelerates the particle : $v_2 > v_1$).  I need to *analytically* find the energy variation from the large circle to the smaller one, to get the final radius $r_2$ (since we don't know the final linear momentum $p_2 = \gamma_2 \, m \, v_2$).

Here's another picture to show some typical trajectories in 3D.  The drift to the center occurs during the transition $B_1 \Rightarrow B_2 > B_1$ :

[A picture in 3D http://s11.postimg.org/yarbwa0ab/induction2.jpg[/img]](http://s11.postimg.org/yarbwa0ab/induction2.jpg[/img])

The drift is caused by the induced electric field, which is kicking the particles with a *local drift velocity* $\vec{\bf v}_d = \vec{\bf E} \times \vec{\bf B}/B^2$.

---

**Complement :**

This may be interesting.  If we consider ***non-relativistic motion*** in a plane only (orthogonal to the magnetic field lines), using polar coordinates give the following ***radial*** differential equation :
\begin{equation}
\ddot{\rho} + \omega^2 \, \rho = \frac{\mathcal{J}^2}{\rho^3},
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{J}$ is the constant of motion defined above (per unit of mass) and $\omega = q B(t)/2m$ is the Larmor angular frequency.  This diff. equation is hard to solve, especially since $\omega$ depends on $t$.  The angular part is given by this equation :
\begin{equation}
\dot{\vartheta} = \frac{\mathcal{J}}{\rho^2} - \omega.
\end{equation}

Comment: The difficulty with my problem is that *the induced electric field isn't conservative* :  the work done is **path dependent**, which is what equ. (8) above shows.  I now suspect that there isn't any analytical solution to my question, unless we do some approximation somewhere !

Comment: I am not sure if this will be helpful, but there is another conserved quantity developed in the Qin paper, I think you derive it's analytic expression with enough turmoil: dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.96.085003

Comment: @Loonuh : Thanks for that paper.  It's actually open only to PhysRev members, but apparently can be found here : https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hong_Qin11/publication/7174191_An_Exact_Magnetic-Moment_Invariant_of_Charged-Particle_Gyromotion/links/5530ac5c0cf2f2a588ab26e2.pdf

Comment: That paper is interesting indeed.  But it's pretty hard to follow in several parts.  The second invariant that it's describing is hard to apply to my problem since it requires some numerical integration, which we could already do with the equation of motion in the first place.  So I don't see much the value of that invariant.

Comment: By the way, the paper indicates how related the problem is to plasma physics.  The second picture I published above shows a gas of particles randomly going closer to each other, by increasing the magnetic field intensity (plasma "heating").  I wasn't aware of that effect.  It's interesting to see a connection to some thermal effects and the fact that the induced electric field is *non-conservative* (like a kind of "friction").

Comment: I've found that if we input an approximate averaged magnetic moment : $\langle \, \vec{\boldsymbol{\mu}} \, \rangle \approx -\, \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\vec{\bf p}_1 \cdot \vec{\bf v}_1}{2 B_1} + \frac{\vec{\bf p}_2 \cdot \vec{\bf v}_2}{2 B_2}) \, \vec{\bf n}$, into the kinetic variation theorem, then we get a reasonably accurate value for the final velocity $v_2$.  But it's working well only when the particle starts close to the solenoid axis.  If the starting point is far away, then this approximation fails.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense since the Bfield is inform right? Have you thought about trying different time variations? I think there are analytical solutions for sinusoidally varying fields. Can you email me at loonuh@ucla.edu and maybe we can discuss more?

Comment: What doesn't make sense ?  The *magnetic* field is uniform, but time varying.  So there's an *non-uniform* electric field induced, and that field affect the motion.  In principle, the velocity change could be found with the kinetic theorem.  The problem is that the electric field work is path dependant (non-conservative).  So an ***approximate*** value of the magnetic moment need to be used, if we want to predict the final velocity.

Comment: The previous averaged magnetic moment approximation gives $v_2 = \sqrt{\frac{B_2}{B_1}} \; v_1$ for the ***non-relativistic*** regime.  Weirdly, this formula works reasonably well even for relativistic motion, according to many trials with the numerical code.  It is relatively accurate when $\frac{q B_1}{2 m} \, \Delta t \gg 1$, i.e. for a long transition time $\Delta t$ compared to the Larmor cyclo-motion period, and only when the start point is very close to the symetry axis.

Comment: The long time transition makes sense because gyrokinetic theory is valid, and the magnetic moment is an (adiabatic) invariant when $\dot{B}/B << $ gyrofrequency.

Comment: What is your initial velocity for the particle? You should keep in mind that if your velocity in the beginning is non-zero, it should correspond also to your unperturbed trajectory, otherwise there is a mismatch between the initial conditions.

Comment: I don't understand.  The initial position and velocity are arbitrary.  How can there be a mismatch between the initial conditions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem simply is not integrable and thus we cannot generally trace the evolution of all phase-space variables analytically. The easiest way to describe it is via a Hamiltonian in cylindrical coordinates
$$H = \frac{(p_\phi - c A_{\phi})^2}{2m \rho^2} + \frac{1}{2m} (p_\rho^2 + p_z ^2)$$
where $A_{\phi}=B(t) \rho /2$ (you can easily see that there is no need for electric potential $\Phi$). The obvious symmetries are rotational leading to the conservation of $p_\phi= m\dot{\phi}\rho^2 + c A_\phi$, and translational, leading to the consevation of $p_z=\dot{z}$. Unfortunately, there are still two degrees of freedom, $\rho$ and $t$ which means that general initial conditions may lead even to chaotic scattering.

If the system truly exhibits chaotic scattering, it is a proof of the fact that you cannot find a general analytical formula. However, sometimes it happens that a system has a "hidden" additional integral. There is no easy way to discern between two cases. I think the easiest thing you can do is resort to some kind of approximation such as assuming $\Delta t$ is small, or on the other hand, that $\Delta t$ is large and you can thus integrate the energy loss as adiabatically evolving through the orbits in the time-independent system.

Comment: This isn't relativistic.  But it's a nice description of the problem for the non-relativistic motion.  What do you mean by "chaotic scattering" ?  And yes, I already found the **approximate solution** from the *adiabatic invariant* (small variations $\Delta B / \Delta t$ imply that the averaged magnetic moment is approximately conserved).